# Lock input and output data

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have main and working threads. These working threads must not stopped before main task is over (i.e. i cant re-creating them with `Thread.Start()`). These working threads reading data from main thread, then writing other data and then main thread writing it in file.
I must use NET 3.5, not including ThreadPool and BackgroundWorker

> InFile -> RawData -> Working -> ReadyData -> OutFile.

```
    public func(string InputFile,string outputFile) {
    ...
    for(int i=0;i<ThreadCount;i++)
    {
        CompressorThreads[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CompressBlock));
        ThreadParam thr = new ThreadParam(i);
        CompressorThreads[i].Start(thr);
    }
    int count;
    while (InputFile.Position < InputFile.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
        {
            count = InputFile.Read(buffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
            RawData[i] = new byte[count];
            /*here activating(start) thread*/
        }
        for (int i = 0; (i < ThreadCount) && (CompressorThreads[i] != null);)
        {
            /*prevent(pause) working thread from changing CompressedData*/
            OutputFile.Write(CompressedData[i], 0, CompressedData[i].Length);
        }

    }
    ...
}
private static void CompressBlock(object BlockProperties)
{
    ThreadParam Block = BlockProperties as ThreadParam;
    int ThreadId = Block.ThreadId;
    while (true)
    {

        if(RawData[ThreadId].Length == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        ...
        /*working here*/
        ...
        /*then save data to CompressedData*/
        /*pause thread*/
    }
}
```

I tried `AutoResetEvent`, but it seems inappropriate for this problem. What i'm looking for?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? If 4.5 or later you might want to use [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (sample code to do file compression [here](http://pragmaticcoding.com/index.php/howto-using-tpl-dataflow-for-multithreaded-file-compression/))

Comment: I must use NET 3.5, not including ThreadPool and BackgroundWorker

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Synchronize access to `CompressedData`? `lock` is not good enough?

Comment: I cant understand how to do it properly. I tried create 2 arrays:
    static object[] RawDataLock = new object[ThreadCount];
    static object[] ReadyDataLock = new object[ThreadCount];
and wrap lock over RawData and CompressionData access, but it doesnt work, file is corrupt. How lock is supporting consistency? I mean, at first, main thread must produce raw data and then working thread consume it

Comment: Looks like a `homework` for me.

Comment: Consistency is a wrong term in multi-thread environment. We say [synchronization](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx).

Comment: I just wanted to say that normally, working threads blocking with each other. In my case,main thread must first write to the `RawData`, then working thread will process it, and then - in the main thread ready data must write to file. I tried `lock` with `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse`, but i dont want block main thread in `Output for`, just skip to the next iteration of `while`. Is it real?

Comment: @Shumek Is it real - no. At the beginning of every `while` iteration you are assigning a new chunk to be processed by the worker, but since you have only 1 buffer slot per worker, you must ensure it's already processed, i.e. the way your current code is structured, you cannot skip the `output` part. Please clarify exactly what you need. Do you insist on the current `while` loop structure? Should the work be scheduled sequentially to workers as it is now? Is one chunk at a time per worker a requirement? etc.